# Capture action signature in middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to capture some metrics using a custom tool about the performance of my web api in middleware. I want to label each metric so that it is easily distinguishable.

I would like to capture the action path, the action method, and the signature in the label. e.g. `POST - /api/values(string param1, string param2, int param3)`

My middleware looks like this:

```
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        // Build metric
        var path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        var method = context.Request.Method;
        var signature = // Is it possible to retrieve something like (string, string, int) here?
        var name = BuildMetricName(path, method, signature);

        var metricId = sdk.BeginMetric(name);

        var delegateTask = next(context);

        //work to service request is done, have sdk end the metric
        sdk.EndMetric(metricId);
        return delegateTask;
    }
```

Compounding matters is the requirement to not slow down processing the request, so any expensive reflection operations would not cut muster.

Comment: You can't obtain "the" action method and "the" signature, because at this point, the route the current request maps to hasn't been determined yet, and routing config is not trivially accessible from another middleware.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's what I presumed, but am at least hoping to get confirmation that what is desired is not possible.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3826, I can't find any more recent discussion about the subject.

Comment: @CodeCaster Appreciate you running this down.